# No connection with proven open port when using mosh (mobile shell)

Tags: linux

I have two connections—home and office—with the same ISP and the same router (WRT 54GL with Tomato Cloud) with almost identical configurations.

I’m unable to establish a [`mosh`](https://mosh.mit.edu) connection from the office using item in Mac OS X to a group of physical Linux servers with `mosh` server installed.

When I work from home, I can safely connect, again with item on Mac OS X using `mosh`.

I tried using Netcat and the required ports seems to work well under both TCP and UDP.

Everything works fine with SSH, but mosh fails telling me it doesn”t receive any data from the server, while Netcat—on the same ports—works well.

The only difference seems to be the client OS, which is Mac OS X in both cases, but I can’t figure, as the firewall is disabled, why Netcat works and `mosh` fails.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is I use netcat I'm able to send and receive both ways. I've also tried with another machine in the office and the result is the same (mosh reports no connection). Tried with both TCP and UDP, because mosh uses UDP for frame diffs and update.